# How do I get my question on a less-used site answered?

Tags: discussion, questions

Note: This is not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) question. My question has no attention, votes, or answers whatsoever.
I have a question on a less-used Stack Exchange site, but no one has answered, and I need an answer. I don't have enough reputation for a bounty, and the chat rooms are dead, so how do I get my question noticed and answered?

Comment: You don't have enough rep? I thought bounties required 75 rep.

Comment: @MARamezani Maybe, but it would put me under 75, and I have no way of gettimg more rep (the site is not used that much.)

Comment: BTW, you can put a bounty of 50 rep and it won't get you lower than 75 rep on PCG. Oh boy, should've flagged that first. I already saw that question a week ago.

Comment: @MARamezani OK, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit it.

Improve it.

Add details. Make it more understandable. Make it easier to answer.

Respond to comments.

And have patience.

Comment: But I've done this, and there are still no answers. It's already gotten the Tumbleweed badge, and I have no options. Is there a place on StackExchange I can link it to for help?

Comment: Not really. Outside of the above and offering a bounty, there isn't much that can be done. Accept that it might not get answered soon.

Comment: OK then. Thanks. Also, what should I do about being marked as a duplicate? Should I delete it?

Comment: You can't delete it (as it has an upvoted answer...). But it does no harm being around.